# How to create a list in a recursive call where the first element needs to be handled differently?

Tags: haskell

I am learning functional programming using Haskell. I am trying to create a function that takes a function f, and executes the function on some input x, n number of times.

```
repeat :: (a -> a) -> a -> Int -> [a]
repeat f x n
```

So, the output list is like this:

```
[x, f(x), f(f(x)), ..., f^n(x)]
```

So far I have been able to come up with a function that I believe does this. It performs n times:

```
fn f a n = f a : fn f (f a) (n-1)
```

The problem I have now, is that I want the first element of the list to just be x. Right now, it is starting my list off at f(x). I tried playing around, but I'm not sure how to cover this "base" case in Haskell. Could someone lend a hand?

Comment: Good luck learning Haskell! You seem to be getting the hang of recursion just fine, which is one of the big stumbling blocks. The language is a bit of a trip, but I promise it's worth it! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You apply the function in two places: once in the "simple" first element case and again in the recursion.

```
fn f a n = f a : fn f (f a) (n-1)
           ^^^         ^^^
```

If you want the first element to be `a`, simply remove the first one; you don't need it.

```
fn f a n = a : fn f (f a) (n-1)
```

Now we have a working function, but it will run forever. You also need a base case. If we tell a function to repeat zero times, we should get the empty list.

```
fn _ _ 0 = []
fn f a n = a : fn f (f a) (n-1)
```

Finally, for readability and by usual Haskell coding standards, we'll want to give this thing a type signature. The most general possible type, which we can query from `ghci` is

```
*Main> :t fn
fn :: (Eq t1, Num t1) => (t2 -> t2) -> t2 -> t1 -> [t2]
```

But it's highly unlikely we're ever going to call this thing with non-`Int` values, and the extra typeclasses may just confuse the inference engine when trying to call it later, so I recommend

```
fn :: (a -> a) -> a -> Int -> [a]
fn _ _ 0 = []
fn f a n = a : fn f (f a) (n-1)
```

Comment: Thanks so much! That makes a lot more sense now! :)

Comment: Another option would be to remove the `Int` parameter and generate an infinite list, and then use a function like `take` to get the desired number of elements.

Answer (score 5):

I would advise to implement this with *two* functions: one where we construct an infinite list, so `(a -> a) -> a -> [a]`, and then we can construct a function `Int -> [a] -> [a]` which takes the first *n* items. Both functions exist in Haskell's `base` package. Indeed, the `fn` function is implemented as [**`iterate :: (a -> a) -> a -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:iterate) and [**`take :: Int -> [a] -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:take).

We can implement `iterate` as:

```
iterate :: (a -> a) -> a -> [a]
iterate f = go
    where go x = x : go (f x)
```

here `x :` thus yields `x` and makes a recursive call with `go (f x)` so the recursive call will yield `f(x)`, and then `f(f(x))`, etc.

The `take` function can be implemented as:

```
take :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
take n _ | n <= 0 = []
take _ [] = []
take n (x:xs) = x : take (n-1) xs
```

Your `fn` function is then:

```
fn :: (a -> a) -> a -> Int -> [a]
fn f x n = take n (iterate f x)
```

Now we thus have two extra utility functions that can be used, not per se for our `fn` function.